# How to get the total time and current time of a video on a web page using python-selenium

Tags: python, selenium

While writing a web automation program, I found that my program does not get the total duration of the video properly (it throws an error)

But I couldn't find any other information to help me

So I came here for help
(I just started using this website and my English is not too good, please excuse me)

Here is part of the code

Thanks

```
            print("Try to find video")
            video = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("video")
            print("Find Video")
            totalTime = video.find_element_by_class_name('duration').get_attribute('textContent')
            print(totalTime)
            while True:
                currentTime = video.find_element_by_class_name('currentTime').get_attribute('textContent')
                print(currentTime)
                if currentTime == totalTime:
                    print("video end")
                    break
                print("isEnd is working!")
```

Comment: What kind of video? Which site are you testing?

Comment: @vitaliis a video using HTML5 tag <video>,and it's a private site.Sorry that i can't tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you might be using a wrong selector.
Example in the youtube videos, you can easily find the youtube total video length by using the xpath `//span[@class='ytp-time-duration']`